# How do I run a node.js function from an html page without using ajax/using express?

Tags: node.js, ajax

I have been having trouble with ajax, and I just want my html to pass a function when a button is passed, but that function is in a node.js file.

How could I do this without AJAX, and if AJAX is required, could I be linked code?

Answer (score -1):

Create `index.js` file and attach it to your `html (index.html)` file.

Then in `html` file if you are submitting form then pass `onClick=functionName()` as `attribute` in `<form>` tag.

In `index.js` file, you can add `functionName` function and that function works as your `frontend` function.

Use `axios` or inbuild `request` to fetch data from that function via `endpoint`.

Comment: he mentioned without ajax